Why does this parameter pack expand to pointers?
At CPPReference it says that the parameter pack is expanded to pointers, why?
template<class... Us>
void f(Us... pargs) {}
 
template<class... Ts>
void g(Ts... args)
{
    f(&args...); // “&args...” is a pack expansion
                 // “&args” is its pattern
}
 
g(1, 0.2, "a"); // Ts... args expand to int E1, double E2, const char* E3
                // &args... expands to &E1, &E2, &E3
                // Us... pargs expand to int* E1, double* E2, const char** E3

Why does Us... expand to pointers?

I don't understand your confusion. You have some int, let's call it E1 like in comments. &E1 is address of that int, so a pointer to int. Now apply that to the whole parameter pack.

What did you think Us would be?

Are you asking why &args... produces pointers?  The & is doing that.

Consider int n = 0; double d = 0.2; char const* s = "a"; f(&n, &d, &s); – you create here pointers to n, d and s which you pass to f – that's the same thing g does (with the sole difference that within g the pointers target the function parameters – which under the hoods are just local variables as well).

lets break it down.
template<class... Us>
void f(Us... pargs)
// takes any number of parameters by copy

 {}
 
template<class... Ts>
void g(Ts... args)
// takes any number of parameters by copy
{
    f(&args...); // each element in pack args is passed by copy then the address of those copies is taken by & operator then the function f deduces types to be <int*,double*,const char**>
}
 
g(1, 0.2, "a"); // Ts... here expands to <int,double,const char*> since it takes by copy




Your comment on the call to f is incorrect.  the address operator is not applied to copies of args....  & is applied to each element of the pack and what is passed is the address of each object in args...

but arent args... here are copies though

They way your comment reads to me it sounds like you are saying arg... gets copied in the call to f and its those copies that get the & applied to it.
